# It's possible to have CKEditor 5 getData() return custom attributes?

Tags: ckeditor5

I've succesfully managed implementing custom attributes creating upcasts and downcasts converters; all seems to work but I'm now blocked on how to get the actual data back from the editor; if I use:

```
editor.getData()
```

I got the html tag (an `<img>` one) without the custom attributes while in the CKEditor Inspector I can see the attributes in both the model and the view.

How I can retrieve the data with the custom attributes?